# Firebase statistics report (sends / impressions)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are trying to monitor the status of our Firebase Cloud Messaging feature in our Android app. We regularly receive feedback from users who say they do not have them.

By checking the Google Firebase reporting tool, we have found that, for the last 30 days, we have a specific number of notifications sent but a reduced number of "impressions", 778K versus 694K.

[image]

We searched the internet for a precise definition of the concept of "impressions" but we could not find it, apart from this (question mark in the chart).

> Number of notification messages seen by users

What does it really means? Why this difference on numbers between sent and seen? Google sent the message to the device but it was "refused" somehow? due to a battery saving software or because of the app is configured to not receive notifications?

We really appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons, why there could be a difference between sent and seen push notifications:

1. Clients may have turned off notifications in the OS for your app. Therefore, Firebase may send the notification to the specific token, but client may not see it.
2. You may have old fcm tokens, that are not valid any more. For example there is registered device in Firebase (or in your backend app), but this device is not active any more. Firebase still tries to send the notification, but there is no guarantee, that client will see it.